# What are some of the best practices for tracking updates to a record over time in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2017-express

I have a product table with a primary key @productid (bigint), a product number (int), and a version (int)

Any time someone makes changes to the product record ONLY, I plan on inserting a new row in the database with the same product number and version number + 1.  This will provide me with the historical tracking I need for the record because I can see the version changes throughout time.

```
/* Selecting the current version is simple */
Select top 1 *
from products
where productnumber = @productnumber
order by version desc
```

However, my problem comes in with the Foreign key one-to-many or many-to-many relationship tables.  This table points to many others (i.e. product pricing with date ranges, product categories, etc.) which also need to be tracked.

```
/* Product categories, pricing */ 
 /* Should I use @productnumber here? How do I track changes to these records? */

select name
from productcategories
where productid = @productid

select price
from productpricing
 where productid = @productid and
       StartDate > @StartDate and
       EndDate <@Enddate
```

So now any time there is a version change, I plan to to re-insert new category and pricing records with the new Primary Key product id that was generated..This is going to lead to a ton of duplicates, especially if no changes were made to these records.

Also the issue comes in with - what happens if a category is removed but there were no changes to the product record?  I would want to see who removed the category.  Essentially, a full audit is needed on each table.

I have seen some different examples but most of them only seem to deal with a record in one table and not a record that is a part of one-to-many or many-to-many relationships.  I was hoping this could be done without the need of additional tables.

Are there any better methods or practices? Is this going to be a performance nightmare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of SQL Server as you are, you can should look into [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) as this might be your best option.

If you need to support older versions, my preferred method is to have a history table with a new PK column, change flag (I,U,D), a date modified, user that made the change, and all of the columns from the primary table. I then index the column related to the PK of the  non-history table. Triggers don't impact performance too much if you don't put logic in them.
Example (pseudocode):

```
Table: Car
Column: CarID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key
Column: Name varchar

Table: Car_hist
Column: Car_histID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key
Column: Change char(1)
Column: DateOfChange DateTime2
Column: ChangedByUser (varchar or int)
Column: CarID <-add a unique non-clustered index
Column: Name varchar
```

You can write a generator in SQL that generates the script to create the history table, indexes, etc. It helps if you have a consistent table design practice.

Now the reason: I rarely have to query history tables, but when I do, it is almost always for a single record to see what happened and who changed it. This method allows you to select from the history on the parent table's PK value quickly and read it as a historical change log easily (who changed what and when). I don't see how you can do that in your design. If you are really slick, you can find or write a grid that diffs rows for you and you can quickly see what changed.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I will be looking into this now.

Comment: So I looked into temporal tables and this does exactly what I need!  I even found a helpful article on Entity Framework & EF Core for anyone that may need it.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795184.aspx